# Programmatically start appengine autoscaled instance

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, warm-up, application-warmup

Is there any way in appengine api to programmatically restart the instance or make it stop so that appengine will spawn another server instance? The reason is during our application servlet, warmpup servlet initialization, due to some network errors, some services are not properly initialized. This causes error when request arrives. We want to know how should we handle this ? Is there any way to handle warmup servlet init exceptions and make container aware so that it will spawn another one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gcloud app instances list` to get the instances, and then `gcloud app instances delete` to kill the instance.

Hope this helps!